# How do I fix a header on scroll using angular 8?

Tags: angular, frontend

I am trying to right a function to fix my header when a user scrolls. Something similar to this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

here's what I have on my html component

```
 <div class="container-fluid main-header" id="myHeader" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)" [ngClass]="'!actives'">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div><a routerLink="/app"><img src="assets/logo/logo.png" width="150px"  class="logo-mobile"></a></div>
    <div class="search-div"> 
      <form action="">
      <input class="search-div" type="text" name="" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for products">
      <div class="show search-icon input-group-append p-2">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
      <button class="hide search-botton">SEARCH</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my the actives class properties in my css file:

```
.actives {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

the function I wrote in my typescript file:

```
actives: boolean;
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  scrollMe(event) {
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var sticky=  header.offsetTop
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
     this.actives;
     console.log("yes bro")
    } else {
     this.actives === false
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use the package called "ng-fixed-element":  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-fixed-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try same code given in example.

```
<div class="container-fluid main-header" id="myHeader" >
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div><a routerLink="/app"><img src="assets/logo/logo.png" width="150px"  class="logo-mobile"></a></div>
    <div class="search-div"> 
      <form action="">
      <input class="search-div" type="text" name="" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for products">
      <div class="show search-icon input-group-append p-2">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
      <button class="hide search-botton">SEARCH</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(){
    ...
    window.onscroll = ()=>{

       let header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
       if (header && window.pageYOffset > header.offsetTop) {
            header.classList.add("actives");
       } else if(header){
            header.classList.remove("actives");
       }
   };
}
```